# what can be used instead of session for storing variables obtained from multiple requests in liferay

Tags: java, liferay

I am using liferay MVC. In the project I have a portlet which hits many different requests say render and request and gets some data from each requests. I am storing the same data in the session for the complete cycle , but if I opens a new tab in the browser the data gets messed up, The data from the recent request overlaps the previous data.

I tried using the model to store the data, even using the new keyword with the object the reference always points to the new request for all the other requests.

So what can be used in place of the sessions for such matters.

here is my sample code:

```
        public void init() throws PortletException {

                viewJSP = getInitParameter("view-template");
                System.out.println("View Jsp is " + viewJSP);
            }
                Modelxyz xyz;
        public void doView(RenderRequest renderRequest,
                    RenderResponse renderResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {
                xyz = new Modelxyz();
                HttpSession session = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(renderRequest)
                        .getSession(false);

                try {
                    themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) renderRequest
                            .getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);

                    List<x> x = xLocalServiceUtil.findByx(true);

                    renderRequest.setAttribute("x", x);
                    session.setAttribute("x,);

                    include(viewJSP, renderRequest, renderResponse);

            }

        public void serveResource(ResourceRequest rrq, ResourceResponse rrr)
                throws PortletException, IOException {
               if (resourceID.equals("gety")) {

      HttpSession session = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(renderRequest)
                        .getSession(false);
      session.getAttribute("x",x);
             y=getY(x);
      session.setAttribute("y",y);
    }else if(resourceID.equals("getz")) {

    //use y to get z

     HttpSession session = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(renderRequest)
                        .getSession(false);
     session.getAttribute("y");

     z=getz(y);

     session.setAttribute("z",z);
    }
```

Even when I tried an model class to store the x and y using the

Modelxyz xyz= new Modelxyz();
//assume this have getters and setters

```
public void serveResource(ResourceRequest rrq, ResourceResponse rrr)
                    throws PortletException, IOException {
                   if (resourceID.equals("gety")) {

        x=xyz.getX();
        y=getY(x);
         xyz.setX(y);

        }else if(resourceID.equals("getz")) {

        //use y to get z


         y=xyz.getY();
         z=getz(y);

         xyz.setZ(z)
        }
```

This too messes up the data when used from the different tabs.What can be the alternative for this ???

Comment: What do you mean by "but if I open a new tab in the browser the data gets messed up"? From what I know, if you visit the same view in two tabs A and B in the same browser, since it's sharing the same user session, then the data that will be stored wil be of the latest tab that sends a request to the server (either A or B). That's the expected behaviour. What do you exactly need? Also, if you use the model to store this data, the model should be stored somewhere else, like session or database, but then again, the scenario I depicted above will raise again.

Comment: Using the model again the data is getting messed up , using the session it was expected to ........but I guess the problem is with the shared object as the reference xyz is always pointing to the most recent object . Now i am looking for the solution where I could store the data from the different tab in the different model object seperately but i am unable to proceed.

Comment: Are you looking to have unique sessions for different tabs within the same browser?Because that is something which is not supported by browser.Try  simulating your scenario with some standard web app such as Gmail or something.Also please be clear on the business scenario being used which requires this logic.

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal : I am looking a way to get some values from many different requests and store them in a common place so that I could use them in any other requests , session was ideal in this case , but i dont want to use the session I want to use something else , as session is creating an problem with the multiple tabs.

Comment: Try setting the data in cookies-easy to store,retrieve and dispose off post interaction.Let me the know of any limitations,if you face any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your "issue", it has nothing to do with Liferay. You are connecting to a web application (that happens to be Liferay in your case). The application server creates a session for you and passes session id (most likely via cookie) back to your browser. The next time your browser sends a request it also provides a session id so the server can associate the request with an active session. That session id would be the same for every request (until the session is invalidated) coming form each and every tab in your browser! So from server perspective it makes no difference if you resend the same request from the same tab or you have a different tab. From server perspective it's just the next request that has session information in it.

From what I see, you are simply setting the value in the session on every `render` request and read it on `serveResource` request. That means if you send more than one `render` request from the same browser (which will have same session id regardless if it is different tab or not) every subsequent request will overwrite the value of the previous one. I guess this is what you call "messes up the data"! If so, the place you store that data is irrelevant.

Therefore the answer to

> what can be used instead of session for storing variables obtained from multiple requests in liferay

is:  **The way you implemented it, it will always "mess up the data" no matter
   where it is stored!**

That said, there are two ways I can think of right away to "solve" the issue:

- you could check if given value is already saved and report back an error on any subsequent request trying to reset it.
- you could introduce some tokens (or in general anything that would allow you to have a "conversation scope"). This way each request would need to indicate which "conversation" it belongs to and you can store the data taking that information into account.

Comment: Hi, I would like to more about the second approach i.e using the "conversation scope" , could you please provide a bit more information how this can be achieved looking into the code I shared.Thanks :)

Comment: Very generally speaking you need to identify a conversation starting point. That could be user loading your page (`render` request) for example. You would check if request has a conversation id parameter. If it doesn't, you would generate new one. Then when rendering the page you generate every link on it in a way that has this conversation id as parameter. 

You can also flip the logic. Use some javascript to identify the browser tab and generate conversation id (or tab id if you prefer) that you send with the request. Then server side use that to store the information separately.

Comment: What I did is I used the jquery to save the values and obtained it on the different step from the jquery , Thanks for the Idea. It worked for me : )